# Related field in osv_memory not working

Tags: orm, relationship, wizard, odoo

I'm building an **osv_memory** wizard in OpenERP 5.

However, it seems that I can't add **related** fields to the wizard.

```
'current_invoice_id': fields.many2one(
                          'account.invoice', 
                          'Invoice'
                      ),
'current_amount_total': fields.related(
                            'current_invoice_id',
                            'amount_total',
                            type='float',
                            store=False,
                            string='Amount'
                        ),
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it just not supported in OpenERP 5?

Comment: It would probably be helpful to describe what happens when you try this.

Answer (score 0):

try using *fields.one2many* instead of *fields.related*.
See [relational types](http://doc.openerp.com/v5.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html#relational-types)

Comment: Try this: `'current_amount_total': fields.one2many(
                            'relation.object',
                            'current_invoice_id',
                            'Amount',
                        ),`

Comment: Or maybe You just wrongly customized relation field? Try: `'current_amount_total': fields.related(
                            'current_invoice_id',
                            'amount_total',
                            type='one2many', relation="relation.object",
                            store=False,
                            string='Amount'
                        ),`

Answer (score 0):

We eventually gave up on `osv_memory` in our OpenERP 5.0 modules. We definitely had problems using `fields.many2one()` from the `osv_memory` table to a regular table, so you may be hitting the same problem.

The good news is that `osv_memory` seems to work well in our tests of OpenERP 6.0.